# Unity Firebase SDK SetRawJsonValue performance

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get my head around an issue with my Unity 2D game where I'm using Firebase Realtime Database to store data like profiles, hits, misses, level progression etc.

For now, I'm working on the scene where users can create a new profile/new character. I've got the following code working:

```
var db = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

Profile profile = new Profile {
    userId = GameManager.Instance.User.UserId,
    name = "Bo Mortensen",
    age = 34,
    gender = "M"
};

string json = JsonUtility.ToJson (profile);

// The Push() is almost instant
var profileKey = db.Child ("profiles").Push ().Key;

// However, this takes around 3 seconds to return, even when specifying 1 as it's priority..
db.Child("profiles").Child(profileKey).SetRawJsonValueAsync (json, 1).ContinueWith (t => {
    if(t.IsFaulted) {
        Debug.Log("Faulted..");
    }

    if(t.IsCanceled) {
        Debug.Log("Cancelled..");
    }

    if(t.IsCompleted) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Main game scene");
    }
});
```

So, creating the actual profile reference for the key is almost instant, where the `SetRawJsonValueAsync` is really slow. Had a test where it took around 5 seconds before it loaded the next scene.

Is this normal for Firebase? I've got a feeling, that I shouldn't wait for the task to return anything and just let it sit in the background working while I load the next scene. This will be really fast, but what if it's canceled or faulted? I'd have no control of that.

Should say that I run my Unity game in debug mode and Firebase is currently the free tier for developing. Not sure if performance would increase with a paid tier of Firebase.

Any help/hint is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There won't be a performance difference from upgrading your Firebase project to a paid plan. All projects run on the same infrastructure.

If this is the first time you interact with the database, you will lose most time establishing the (web socket) connection between client and server. After that performance is mainly dependent on the amount of data you send vs. the bandwidth you have available. These are the two most common causes and completely out of the control of your application code.

A quick way to check if you're losing time setting up the initial connection is to run the code that writes a few times after each other. If the next calls are significantly faster, you're paying the cost of building the initial connection. There is nothing you can do to prevent that cost, but you may be able to hide it by interacting with the database earlier in your app lifecycle, e.g. by reading/writing a dummy value on startup.

The main other place I could imagine time going would be in the parsing of the JSON. But your object structure seems quite small, so that seems unlikely here.

It's typically safe to transition before the task completes. The `isCancelled()` will only be true if the data is rejected by your server-side security rules. Since you control both the code and the security rules, that should normally not happen in production. But I'm not really certain when the client would return `true` for `IsFaulted()`. That call is not present in the underlying iOS and Android SDK's, so I don't know when the Unity client raises this condition.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank ! Very, very valuable information right there. I tried to create a separate method for creating dummy data in the database and the first was slow, as you mentioned, but after that, data was stored instantly !

One thing that comes to mind: this should *really* be included in the SDK guides :-) Honestly, I was close to look for alternatives to Firebase just because of that simple misunderstanding.

Anyway: thank you so much again. That just saved my day :-)

Comment: Good to hear that it was the initial connection. Most application types that use Firebase, use it from the moment they start. So the cost to create the connection is both hidden in the general startup cost and can't be further hidden in that case. In your system it seems that you don't use the database until later, in which case there are ways to hide the cost. But this is indeed one of those cases where our generic approach to documentation might not have helped.